# SharePoint 2013 Custom Action Group - Icon Missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have created a custom group, and added an Icon for the button. For some reason the Icon is not showing up in the display. If I add the Icon to an existing group, it will work without any problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroupInExsitingTab" 
              RegistrationType="List" 
              RegistrationId="101" 
              Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" >
  <CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Scaling._children">
        <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup.MaxSize" 
                 GroupId="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup" 
                 Size="LargeLargev" 
                 Sequence="10" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Scaling._children">
        <Scale Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup.LargeSmall" 
               Sequence="230" 
               GroupId="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup" 
               Size="LargeSmall" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Groups._children">
        <Group Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup"
               Sequence="10"
               Title="Custom Group"
               Template="Ribbon.Templates.Flexible2"
               Image32by32Popup="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png">
          <Controls Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup.Controls">
            <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup.Notify"
                  Command="CustomGroup.Command.Notify"
                  Sequence="15"
         Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png"
         Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png"

                  Description="Notification hello message"
                  LabelText="Notify"
                  TemplateAlias="o1" />
          </Controls>
        </Group>
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
      <CommandUIHandler Command="CustomGroup.Command.Notify" 
                        CommandAction="javascript: SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Hello from my custom group);  " />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
  </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

Comment: Updated solution and functioning http://pastebin.com/w8fxJRPQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding "15" after _layouts. For ex. /_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=33

Alternatively, you could open Firebug/IE developer tool to see where the image src is pointing to. That would give you some information

Comment: The image reference was part of the problem, plus the code was overly complex for what I was trying to accomplish.